# Is dark matter unmanifested matter?

Tags: dark-matter

I am by no means a physicist. I lack credentials and formal education. I did however have an interest in theoretical physics when I was younger. This post is to present my thoughts/idea/theory or however you want to phrase it. I wrote this excerpt in my book, ... the book is spiritual, and has a little insight of mine on my beliefs concerning God and dark matter. In an effort to not make two posts, I will join them together in this post. Before you close this post and exit it because I said God, ... let me just win you over by saying that my perception of God is not religious ... so whatever I do say, will be in my own mind - complimentary to science.

First off, let me just say that I have read it is polite to post thoughts/ideas in the form of a question. I apologize, but I will not be doing that. I appreciate if anyone chooses to respect my approach in explaining this... which will simply be a copy/paste and excerpt directly from my book, with no question marks.

DARK MATTER:
"Dark matter is an alluring mystery to the greatest thinkers and astrophysicists in this world. Dark matter does not emit or absorb light, yet it causes gravitational lensing to occur in the perception between us and a galaxy we are attempting to view. We can see beyond dark matter as in through it, but we cannot identify what is truly is. We fail to record any radiation coming from the dark matter, so what is it? It is my feeling that it is the unmanifest, a conception contained in a sort of paradox. Dark matter exists in a state of conception before its creation. It has volume, takes up space and has a weak interaction with other dark matter. In a sense, it is physical as far as we can perceive without touching it ourselves. It holds a presence that is evidential by gravitational lensing. If dark matter is perceived in a way where light beyond it is warped when observed, it must hold clue on how we perceive matter.

Unmanifest? If you have not heard of this concept, I suggest you research it more on your own. The unmanifest is creation before its conception. It is understood in Jewish mysticism and is a vital mechanic within the Tree of Life. Keter, the highest Sephira, is the source of the unmanifest. It is the “air that cannot be held” … it holds all the unthinkable which is simply all that has not been yet known. As it is unthinkable, it is also unknowable.

Perhaps dark matter is the shadow of something we have yet to know. As the dark matter is a creation we cannot perceive, we glimpse into the reality that much can exist beyond our observation. Dark matter is a vacuum for intelligence, yet that intelligence is unmanifested. It is the phenomenon of the unimagined. All that we may perceive in this universe is all that our mind is capable of perceiving. We will not perceive dark matter in its true state if it is unknown to the workings of our mind. It is vital we understand something else the Kabbalah communicates, the unmanifest is simultaneously manifested. It exists in both states of the expressed and unexpressed because time is not a barrier to creation.

We will find that dark matter generates matter. “Matter cannot be created nor destroyed” … Between the two states of matter is a spectrum of nothingness to wholeness. Atoms are described to be the smaller building blocks of matter, that break off into lighter elements until they reach a state where they no longer split. The state that is reached is like the fabric of spacetime, the same as the strings of String Theory. That is the far-reaching conclusion of something forming into nothing. Dark matter is nothing forming into something. Matter has the illusion of being destroyed, and dark matter has the illusion of being created. We observe dark matter as it holds together galaxies as if it is ‘something’ … but remember, that it is created as nothing because it has not reached a state of becoming something."

Now, after you have fininshed reading my thoughts, and I hope you liked it. Now, I will discuss 'God' ... or what I term as an "all-natural singularity" that exists within the inception of the Big Bang theory. I am pretty "out there" in terms of not being grounded in practical rationality, and I am far from pragmatic. This is because my approach is with my creative mind, not as much as playing with the building blocks of proven science (or whatever is proven or has to be proven) ...

GOD AS AN ALL-NATURAL SINGULARITY:
PART ONE:
"The cause of the all-natural singularity is the effect of all intelligence. The all-natural singularity is an eternally present cosmic event that exists in the essence of spacetime. The essence of spacetime exists in mind. Infinite intelligence is existing in a state of matter in the midst of conception. This source gives a human conception of the Big Bang theory which de-livers dimensions to the active intelligence of our creation. Nature is that intelligence in effect. The singularity is serving as an alpha, and the polarizing singularity as the omega."

PART TWO:
"The dimensions of time separate the paralleling realities of space. It is upon the conception of these realities being impregnated by dimensions of time that we find ourselves caught in the moment of life as we have come to understand it in nature. The beginning and the end both connect within one singularity, of which an everlasting life-force originates from like a wellspring. It is like the shape of a torus, and it is a great source of energy. Energy is recycled through transfigurations within the singularity, at the speed of its increasing intelligence. It affects all surrounding existence and serves as the working algorithmic intelligence for the applied universe."

Looking forward to reading any thoughts or criticisms.
Thank you for letting share :)

Comment: *"GOD AS AN ALL-NATURAL SINGULARITY: PART ONE:"* - flagged and voting to close.

Comment: You get that the point of Physics is to make falsifiable predictions, right?

Comment: or provable predictions.

Comment: But not this stuff he is presenting.

Answer (score 2):

Wow that's some trippy stuff and wild imagination you've got there :)

Anyway, no dark matter is not mystic matter. We don't know what it is exactly - that's why it's called "dark", though probably out of habit the terminology may end up retained after we do. Our best guess is it's particles of matter just like other matter, just ones we don't have in our existing models of physics yet. There's nothing at all to suggest it has any magic, supernatural, or paranormal characteristics, though we've only so far observed it to interact via gravity, and as it does so it does so in the way we'd expect any other kind of massive matter to behave (strongly counterindicating that it's any kind of magical/mystic woo wooey stuff and just an ordinary part of the Universe we don't have a model for yet.). One interesting candidate idea so far is Axions - small, light particles that essentially "froze" during the Big Bang and can be accommodated with some modest extensions to our existing physical models that also help to patch up some holes in them elsewhere, and experiments are underway to try and detect this. There are other possibilities as well, but a fair number have been mostly ruled out or partially ruled out by other experiments and observations now (including the idea that dark matter doesn't exist at all but is actually an artifact of a deeper modification of gravitational laws - this especially with the latest discovery of a galaxy with NO dark matter, which suggests it can't be an inherent property of gravitational forces itself, but rather actually a real, detachable matter.). It's an aggravating puzzle but that's what's so great about this stuff! :) But no, no magic.